Handling Emits with Vue.extend in TypeScript
I'm following the Vue 3 migration guide and trying to declare all the $emit events in the emits array. My component is written in TypeScript, and I'm still using Vue.extend. However, I'm encountering a type error when adding the emits property.
original code:
import Vue from 'vue';

export default Vue.extend({

props: {

    message: String,

},

methods: {

    sendMessage() {
    
      this.$emit('message-sent');
    
    },

},

template: `

    <div @click="sendMessage">
    
      {{ message }}
    
    </div>

`,

});

</script\>

what im trying to write:
import Vue from 'vue';

export default Vue.extend({

name: 'MessageComponent',

emits: \['message-sent'\],

...


However, I'm getting the following type error:
TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'emits' does not exist in type 'ComponentOptions<Vue<Record<string, any>, Record<string, any>, never, never, (event: string, ...args: any[]) => Vue<Record<string, any>, Record<string, any>, never, never, ...>>, ... 7 more ..., ComponentOptionsMixin>'.


It seems like the emits property is not recognized by Vue.extend. How can I correctly declare the emits array in my component while still using Vue.extend to resolve this type error?

You probably shouldn't. The question is for v2, where emits doesn't do anything useful. If it's not recognized as an option, it cannot be even used for TS type checks
